# d3 v4 - zoom with buttons in conflicts with zoom behaviour

Tags: javascript, zooming, pan, d3.js

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nkint/55a7f53ae6bcdb4362e8232270a365da) with my problem.

I've started from [this example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3127661b6f13f9316be745e77fdfb084).

So my problem is that I need some zoom in and zoom out buttons in addition to mouse controls.

Mouse controls (zooming with wheel and pan by dragging) are implemented with [zoom() behaviour](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md). It works pretty well.

Then I've added two buttons for zoom in and zoom out:

```
var _zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
var gui = d3.select("#gui")
gui.append("span")
  .classed("zoom in", true)
  .text("+")
  .on("click", function() { _zoom.scaleBy(container, 2); })
gui.append("span")
  .classed("zoom out", true)
  .text("-")
  .on("click", function(){ _zoom.scaleBy(container, 0.5); })
```

They are in conflict with the mouse behaviour. To reproduce the bug you have to zoom and drag around (with the mouse controls) and then click on the `+` span: the current transformation is overwritten.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that the zoom transform is stored on the `node`, **NOT** in the `_zoom` object.

In your case you set the mouse listener on the `svg` node,

```
svg.call(_zoom);
```

When a zoom event is triggered on the `svg` element, you then take the updated zoom transform of the `svg` node and apply it to the `g` node,

```
g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
```

All you need to do when updating the zoom of the g element on the button click is grab the correct transform, in your case that of the `svg` node,

```
 _zoom.scaleBy(svg, 0.5);
```

Which will trigger the zoom event on the `svg` node correctly, updated in full below,

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");
svg.style("border", "solid 1px black");
var points = d3.range(2000).map(phyllotaxis(10));
var g = svg.append("g");

var _zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
  .on("zoom", function() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  });
svg.call(_zoom);

var container = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 2.5)

function phyllotaxis(radius) {
  var theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
  return function(i) {
    var r = radius * Math.sqrt(i),
      a = theta * i;
    return {
      x: width / 2 + r * Math.cos(a),
      y: height / 2 + r * Math.sin(a)
    };
  };
}
var gui = d3.select("#gui");
gui.append("span")
  .classed("zoom in", true)
  .text("+")
  .on("click", function() {
    _zoom.scaleBy(svg, 2);
  });
gui.append("span")
  .classed("zoom out", true)
  .text("-")
  .on("click", function() {
    _zoom.scaleBy(svg, 0.5);
  })
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<div id="gui"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```